# Efectuar operacion al detectar el cambio en un item QtableWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Tengo un `QTableWidget`, de 3x5 en el item (5, 5) efectúo la suma de los numero que ingresen dentro del ítem (1,2) y (1,3).

Actualmente necesito que el usuario de click en un botón *actualizar* para poder efectuar la actualización pero quisiera saber si hay una manera de evitar esto y que directamente se ejecute la operación cuando cambie algún valor.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que la operación se efectué al momento de detectar el cambio de valor de alguno de los 2 items?

Código:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from tabla import tabla_style

class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("new_exe.ui",self)

        self.tabla_1 #QtableWidgetInstanciado desde un archivo.ui


app = QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes dos señales a tu disposición en `QtTableWidgets` para detectar el cambio de contenido en una celda de la tabla:

- [`QTableWidget.itemChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#itemChanged): te permite obtener la instancia de `QtTableWidget.Item` cuyos datos fueron modificados.
- [`QTableWidget.cellChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#cellChanged): te permite obtener la fila y la columna (índices enteros) de la celda en la que está el item cuyos datos fueron modificados.

Dejo un ejemplo de una tabla dónde se usan las dos señales, los slots solo imprimen la posición de la celda, en ellos puedes desplegar la lógica que te permita hacer lo que quieras que ocurra cuando se modifique ciertas celdas:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets



class Ejemplo(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resize(690, 300)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 680, 290))
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(3)

        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5'])
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderLabels(["A", "B", "C"])

        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(5):
                item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
                item.setText(str(i + j))
                self.tableWidget.setItem(i, j, item)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)


        self.tableWidget.cellChanged.connect(self.on_cell_changed)
        self.tableWidget.itemChanged.connect(self.on_item_changed)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int, int)
    def on_cell_changed(self, row: int, col: int) -> None:
        print(f"Se modificó la celda ({row}, {col})")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem)    
    def on_item_changed(self, item: QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem) -> None:
        print(f"Se modificó el item en posición ({item.row()}, {item.column()})")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Ejemplo()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```